# How to allow spaces in between words?

Tags: regex

EDIT: I've been experimenting, and it seems like putting this:

```
\(\w{1,12}\s*\)$
```

works, however, it only allows space at the end of the word.

example,

Matches

```
(stuff )
(stuff    )
```

Does not

```
(st uff)
```

Regexp:

```
\(\w{1,12}\)
```

This matches the following:

```
(stuff)
```

But not:

```
(stu ff)
```

I want to be able to match spaces too.

I've tried putting `\s` but it just broke the whole thing, nothing would match. I saw one post on here that said to enclose the whole thing in a `^[]*$` with space in there. That only made the regex match everything.

This is for Google Forms validation if that helps. I'm completely new to regex, so go easy on me. I looked up my problem but could not find anything that worked with my regex. (Is it because of the parenthesis?)

Comment: `\w` matches a word character. Space is not a word character, so it will never be matched using `\w`.

Comment: ...`[\w\s]{1,12}`...

Comment: The question never says what you're actually trying to do with this regular expression.

Comment: So you want a single word surrounded by spaces in parentheses?

Comment: What language/flavor? Could you add a tag please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get 12 characters between parentheses:

```
\([^\)]{1,12}\)
```

The `[^\)]` segment is a character class that represents all characters that aren't closing parentheses (`^` inverts the class).

If you want some specific characters, like alphanumeric and spaces, group that into the character class instead:

```
\([\w ]{1,12}\)
```

Or

```
\([\w\s]{1,12}\)
```

If you want 12 word characters with an arbitrary number of spaces anywhere in between:

```
\(\s*(?:\w\s*){1,12}\)
```

Answer (score 1):

For matching text like `(st uff)` or `(st uff some more)` you will need to write your regex like this,

```
\(\w{1,12}(?:\s+\w{1,12})*\)
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `\(` - Literal start parenthesis
- `\w{1,12}` - Match a word of length 1 to 12 like you wanted
- `(?:\s+\w{1,12})*` - You need this pattern so it can match one or more space followed by a word of length 1 to 12 and whole of this pattern to repeat zero or more times
- `\)` - Literal closing parenthesis

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vbmTPN/1)**

Now if you want to optionally also allow spaces just after starting parenthesis and ending parenthesis, you can just place `\s*` in the regex like this,

```
\(\s*\w{1,12}(?:\s+\w{1,12})*\s*\)
  ^^^                        ^^^
```

**[Demo with optional spaces](https://regex101.com/r/vbmTPN/2)**